# Is it still considered research if my goal is not to publish?

Tags: research-undergraduate

I began working on a fairly complex project with a few friends a few months back. It began as a hobby project, but became more serious as we realized how effective it may be. We collaborated with a professor a fair amount, and he registered us as 'undergraduate researchers' with the university. He is listed as our official mentor, but just gives advice when we have questions rather than steering the research.

We have no intention of publishing, and we are not even sure if our research is novel. We do incorporate very rigorous topics in our project, and I am wondering how I should describe this to Grad schools. "Undergraduate Research Project" seems misleading, but it seems like the most apt way to describe it. Thoughts?

Comment: What sounds misleading? You did a research project as an undergraduate under the supervision of a faculty member. V confused

Comment: I see that it might be hard to judge without some context. The project involves exploring applications of Machine Learning to derivatives trading, and we are developing a platform to analyze the effectiveness of various ML techniques.

Comment: I just assume that undergraduate research implies that the ultimate goal is publishing, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Nope. Most of my undegraduate projects won't be published. (Some are/were though).

Comment: The "publication" game is a-priori unrelated to trying to uncover new things (=actual research). But, unsurprisingly, administrators and other bean counters want to have something measurable, etc. (to explain to everyone why they're failing, according to some random standard, thus explaining why they don't get better raises...) Advancing collective understanding is the real goal, no matter how various bureaucrats wish to formalize it.

Comment: Knowing whether your work is novel seems a necessary part of research. Per definition, research is about expanding the boundaries of knowledge. So you would first need to know what the current knowledge is before you can expand it.

Comment: I'd say "research", in the academic sense, should have some component of contributing to overall human knowledge, not just your own.  Will you be publicizing your results in some other way than traditional publishing (tech report, open-source software, preprint)?  If it's strictly for your own learning or curiosity, I would call it "faculty-led project", "independent study", or some similar term, but not "research".

Comment: What _is_ your goal? What are you and your collaborators planning to do with the software you develop and the results of your analysis of the effectiveness of machine learning techniques for derivatives trading?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to utilize our findings to trade and make money, but as of right now it is a mostly academic endeavor. I think that @NateEldredge is right and it should be considered an academic project, rather than research.

Comment: @paulgarrett : How do you advance **collective** understanding if you do not publish?

Comment: @Distic, "publication" in the sense of "making it available on the internet", is not the same as "go through the stylized so-called peer-review process" (not to mention documents ending up behind pay-walls), the latter being the main thing that administrators call "publication"... since it is vastly more restrictive.

Comment: @paulgarrett: I think in our context, nobody spoke to make anything available on the Internet. And the peer review process avoids anyone publishing on the Internet to claim he is doing science, which is itself good.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you publish, and whether or not it's novel, your effort certainly satisfies all reasonable definitions of 'research project'. You may use the term with impunity.